# Search/Filter option in Gridview using Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to provide search option in Gridview so that user will find the exact match from the large data from the gridview. There are solution available when we set the Autogenerate property to "true" and sqlDataSource set in .aspx page. But I am generating columns dynamically in code. How to do. Pls help...!
GridView :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ItemGrid" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="90%" 
     onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" BorderStyle="Solid" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" 
                 onpageindexchanging="ItemGrid_PageIndexChanging">
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF9900" BorderColor="White" Height="40px"  HorizontalAlign="Center"  Font-Bold="True" />
 <RowStyle BorderColor="White"  Width="30px" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
 <AlternatingRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="Silver" />                    
             </asp:GridView>
```

Generating Columns in Code behind:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
```

//generating gridview header cells
}

Any Idea how to add search/Filter option in this case..?

Comment: Not clear what you want and also what did you tried ?

Comment: You should show what you have tried, otherwise this question is too broad since it asks for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

i did in my code

```
public void filterd5()
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "";
        SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
        //GridView1.DataBind();
        if (ddlfilter.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "toad1 LIKE '%{0}%' or toad2 LIKE '%{0}%' or toad3 LIKE '%{0}%' ";
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("toad1", TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("toad2", TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("toad3", TextBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (ddlfilter.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "fromad1 LIKE '%{0}%' or fromad2 LIKE '%{0}%' or fromad3 LIKE '%{0}%' ";
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("fromad1", TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("fromad2", TextBox1.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("fromad3", TextBox1.Text);
        }

        else if (ddlfilter.SelectedValue == "3")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "fromtaluk LIKE '%{0}%' ";
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("fromtaluk", TextBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (ddlfilter.SelectedValue == "4")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "totaluk LIKE '%{0}%'";
            SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("totaluk", TextBox1.Text);
        }

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filterd5();
        // GridData();
    }
```

> where fromad, fromtaluk, totaluk are columns header. in dropdown i bind all headers